# storing json data from a file in local variable

Tags: json, angular, angular2-services

I want to load data from a local .json file and store the content in a local variable, that is accessible throughout the program. I have this function inside my service which I call to get the data.

```
GetData(){
this.d={Data:[],number:[]}
this.http.get('data.json').map(res =>res.json()).subscribe(res=>
 {this.d=(res);
  console.log(this.d); //this.d gets the value from res and prints the expected value
  });
console.log(this.d);//this.d gets printed as empty
return this.d;
}
```

this.d seems to get the value from res inside the subscribe portion, but once outside subscribe when I try to print it it seems to be empty. d is declared as an object. What could possibly be the error?

Comment: Did you declare variable d?

Comment: Thanks for the response. @Ripon. Yes, i have. i have declared d as d:Object in the class.

Comment: The first A in AJAX means **Asynchronous**. So you can't expect to have the response in your variable right after you sent the request. The variable will be populated when the response comes back, later, asynchronously. If AJAX was synchronous, htto.get() would return the response directly, and wouldn't bother you with observables that you need to subscribe to.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JBNizet. I am sorry for the very basic nature of the question, I am just learning some of these concepts. My understanding is that the variable, this.d gets populated with the values once the response comes back and I am able to print and check the same within subscribe(). What I don't understand is why does this.d not carry the value it was assigned to inside subscribe, once you try to print it right after as in the above code. It would be super helpful if you could elaborate more on your answer or refer a link on this. Thanks again!

Comment: It does carry its value after it was assigned to. But the line that is just after the call to http.get(...) is executed **long before** the assignment inside the callback function passed to subscribe(). It's executed immediately after the request has been sent. Think of asynchronism with a toaster: immediately after you put bread in a toaster, it's not toasted yet. So you can do something else, like reading the news, or drinking an orange juice. It's only after the toaster dings that you can start using your toasted bread.

Comment: `this.d=(res)` is what happens after the ding. `return this.d` is what happens just after you put the bread in the toaster. The bread is not toasted yet at that time.